# How to share constants from Java to C#?

Tags: java, c#

I'm writing a client server application including a communication system. The protocol includes tokens to define message types. On the server (Java) I use Enumerations for the message types with a corresponding String value (the actual message type). Of course, the types must match on the client (C#).

Is there a way to export this so is always in sync?

I just don't want to reinvent the wheel. I was thinking of writing code to create a cs file from Java, but wanted to make sure I'm not over complicating myself.

Comment: It just so happens that [Java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and [C# enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) share the same basic syntax; you'd simply copy a `.java` to a `.cs` or vice versa. You could use the names of the enums at runtime in both languages to represent the protocol string values.

Comment: Kenney's advice only holds if you're using trivial Enum behavior in Java, unfortunately. The only feature I find myself missing from Java in C# is the ability to give enum instances methods. So powerful.  The long and short of it, though is that I wouldn't endeavor to sync it so much as acknowledge that the C# and Java versions are separate related codebases, and that fidelity is going to be something requiring discipline.

Comment: As stated, the question is pretty broad. As noted above, if using simple enum types in both languages, you could copy/paste. Alternatively, you could use a code-generation step (e.g. T4) to automatically generate the appropriate source code for each language from a common input file. Another option is to forego actual `enum` types and instead write a class that defines named values at runtime based on an input file.

Comment: Kenney, please make your comment an answer so I can mark it. This is the approach I used. For the rest, I believe they are relevant answers for other scenarios. So please make them proper answers to give you points. In my case it was a plain Enum and I was able to make it work.